# Problem with DAX calculated column "A table of multiple values was supplied where a single value was expected"

Tags: powerbi

here is my code below and error is as in subject of the post.

```
P24 Part Number =
VAR part =
    LOOKUPVALUE (
        SMNs[P24 Part Number],
        SMNs[SMN], 'Shipment Volume'[P41 Part Number]
    )
RETURN
    IF ( ISBLANK ( part ), 'Shipment Volume'[P41 Part Number], part )
```

It's saying that table 'Shipment Volume'[P41 Part Number] of multiple values supplied where a single value was expected. This table have all unique values and I'm stuck. Please advise.

Comment: Please read the official documentation before posting questions here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the official [LOOKUPVALUE()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/lookupvalue-function-dax) documentation, the function has the following signature:

```
LOOKUPVALUE(
    <result_columnName>,
    <search_columnName>,
    <search_value>,
    <alternate_result>
)
```

In your formula you have:

- <result_columnName>: SMNs[P24 Part Number]
- <search_columnName>: SMNs[SMN]
- <search_value>: 'Shipment Volume'[P41 Part Number]
- <alternate_result>: 'Shipment Volume'[P41 Part Number]
  *(from the unnecessary IF clause)*

The problem is that 'Shipment Volume'[P41 Part Number] is a column, not a single value. So this won't work in a measure, but in a **Calculated Column** only where you have a row context:

```
P24 Part Number = 
LOOKUPVALUE (
    SMNs[P24 Part Number],
    SMNs[SMN], 'Shipment Volume'[P41 Part Number], 
    'Shipment Volume'[P41 Part Number]
)
```

Comment: Hi Peter, thank you for quick feedback! What do you suggest as how to rewrite the calculated Column to make it work? Sorry, fairly new to DAX still learning!

Comment: Apologize, just realized you provided correct DAX and it did work! Thank you so much for help!